# How to typeset a two column parallel poem?

Tags: two-column, comparison, poetry

I got this double column poem written by some friends that is meant to be typeset with
the stanzas in parallel. Here is a sample:

```
Tiempos en pausa.                                                          Tiempo.

Pausa que como hoyo negro se traga todo.                                   Pausa que como hoyo negro
Todo al mismo tiempo traga y al mismo tiempo vacía.                        todo
Vacío que abrasa y abraza.                                                 vacía y
Abrazo que devora y a su vez escupe y devuelve.                            abraza.
```

I think the verse environment would not support this multi column arrangement.
And the paracol may be a little of an overshoot, as it needs to be instructed to
jump from one column to the next every time. Is there a more sensible solution?

Comment: Maybe a `tabularx` with two columns?

Answer (score 1):

Okey, it seems that `paracol` did the trick reasonably well.
I guess it was only matter of typing in an orderly manner the verses!

```
\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}

  
  \poemtitle{Tiempos en pausa.}
  \switchcolumn
  \poemtitle{Tiempo.}
  \switchcolumn

 \begin{verse}
   \textbf{Pausa que como hoyo negro} se traga todo. \\
  \textbf{Todo} al mismo tiempo traga y al mismo tiempo vacía. \\
  \textbf{Vacío} que abrasa y abraza. \\
  \textbf{Abrazo} que devora y a su vez escupe y devuelve. \\
  \end{verse}
  
  \switchcolumn
  \begin{verse}
 
  Pausa que como hoyo negro \\
  todo \\
  vacía y \\
  abraza. \\ 
      
  \end{verse}

  \switchcolumn
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe worth checking out: the `bidi`package, originally designed to help with documents interchanging between LTR and RTL blocks, offers an environment called `traditionalpoem`. I tried this real quick and it seems that it is generally usable for your question. Here comes a quick & dirty solution, possibly someone can still improve upon this.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bidipoem}
\usepackage[landscape=true]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{traditionalpoem}
    Tiempos en pausa.&                                                          
    Tiempo.\\
    
    Pausa que como hoyo negro se traga todo.&                                   
    Pausa que como hoyo negro\\
    Todo al mismo tiempo traga y al mismo tiempo vacía.&                        
    todo\\
    Vacío que abrasa y abraza.&                                                 
    vacía y\\
    Abrazo que devora y a su vez escupe y devuelve.&                            
    abraza.
\end{traditionalpoem}


\end{document}
```

[image: Poem typeset in a mediocre way.]

Further information on the package is scarce, but maybe have a look [over here too](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640685/looking-to-typeset-2-columned-persian-poem-in-classicthesis-document-that-is-oth?noredirect=1&lq=1).